# embed video in a view controller ios

Tags: iphone, ios, video, storyboard

I have a json file which includes data and between this data I have a video field.

how can I embed a video object in a view controller, what shall I put in the interface builder?? 
I cannot find video object in the objects existed on the right side.
see below:

[image]

Shall I add some libraries? I need to help me how can I play a video object on my application.

I need your help please.

Answer (score 0):

Just load the files into UIWebView, it can handle both videos and PDFs.

OR

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1240.html

Answer (score 0):

There is really good class for it [VideoPlayerKit](https://github.com/ign/VideoPlayerKit). Using VideoPlayerKit is easy to use. All controls, progress bar, and airplay are already set up.

This is example's screen

[image: VideoPlayerKit]