# How to embed a video in a container in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, video, ios7

I make a container in a View Controller. That container is also a normal UI View Controller.

I want the video (in say m4v or mp4 format) to play in an infinite loop. I do not want the want the video to have any controls and I do not want the video to present itself full screen, just the size of the container. Does this mean the video should be played modal in the container view controller?

I tried doing this, the video nor the container would not show up. I have tried looking into this question and it did not help:
[embed video in a view controller ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482328/embed-video-in-a-view-controller-ios)

Or how should I embed an animation instead that plays itself in an infinite loop.